# How to process time-consuming tasks in a distributed way?

Tags: java, distribution, distributed-computing

We need to process tasks that take a lot of time (parsing huge xml files and inserting the data into db) by multiple nodes. The nodes will not be many, we are even going to start with a single node.

The files are going to be read from an FTP. The job will be scheduled and will happen once a day. What would be a good and easy way to distribute the processing?

My current draft thoughts are:

- use hazelcast distributed `ConcurrentMap` - it handles the synchronization of the map behind the scene
- each node takes the whole list of files and shuffles it
- then each node iterates the list, using `.putIfAbsent(..)` - if the file is not in the map, process it. If it is in the map, it means another node is processing it, so try the next file.

That way:

- nodes will never be idle
- if a node fails, other nodes will still process everything (just slower)
- since the files are big and it takes a lot of time to process them, there will be little contention overhead in the `.putIfAbsent(..)` call and the underlying synchronization (shuffling is meant to improve this as well)
- it requires minimal configuration and does not require installing and managing additional services (like a message queue)

I'm not sure if this is the best approach though. Is it OK? What can be improved? Is there a better one?

Comment: I would use a JMS queue to distribute the work as each worker will naturally obtain the next task. The putIfAbsent approach as the advantage of avoiding duplicate tasks though I am not sure have you ensure the tasks are distributed fairly (or how you restart a failed task)

Comment: who is going to fill the queue? If it is one node, and it fails? Also, a JMS queue would require managing a JMS service

Comment: The producer of tasks add to the queue. If a node fails and auto-commit is off, the task doesn't leave the queue proper until it is committed. If the node fails before this happens, the message is appears in the queue again. You need one or JMS brokers but these can be embedded if you prefer. i.e. without a separate process.

Comment: ok, that sounds like a good option. But filling the queue with the filenames remains debatable - one node should have the scheduled job of filling the queue. What if it is dead at that moment?

Comment: You can have any number of nodes adding to the queue, but it won't remove duplicates if that what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want - each file should be there only once

Comment: No matter how many times you add it?

Comment: Yes. The filesystem is shared (FTP, actually), and all nodes read from it. So each file should have exactly one corresponding task

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments I would suggest considering using JMS, (like ActiveMQ which I found the simplest to use/develop with)

It can be stand-alone, redundant and/or embedded.

You can add messages to a Queue and consume from any number of nodes. With auto-commit turned off a failing nodes messages are returned to the queue automatically.

Comment: Don't you mean AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGMENT turned off? Auto-commit is more rdbms terminology.

Comment: @raffian The terminology is a little inconsistent. Commit is also used http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Session.html#commit()